# Dynamically Create Controls Based Off Data Returned From Query

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label

I am querying access table and with my data that is returned I need to be able to create controls.  Now the problem with my code is (I obviously need to learn about loops better than I do) the code executes exactly as it should it does the 1st foreach loop then moves to the 2nd foreach loop.  So I have all the labels - then I have all the text boxes.  I need it to be a 1 to 1 relationship. So Label Text box.  This is my current code that is not producing the desired outcome.  Can someone assist me in tweaking this to produce the desired outcome of a 1 to 1 relationship of label to textbox

```
System.Collections.Hashtable lookup = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
OleDbConnection olecon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +     oName);
olecon.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Query Data Goes Here", olecon);
OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand("Query Data Goes Here", olecon);
dr = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
  labelNames.Add(dr[0].ToString());
}
dr.Close();
dr = command1.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
  textboxNames.Add(dr[0].ToString());
}
dr.Close();
foreach (string label in labelNames)
{
  Label lbl = new Label();
  lbl.Name = "lbl_" + index;
  lbl.Text = label;
  lbl.AutoSize = true;
  Form1.Controls.Add(lbl);
  index++;
}
foreach (string textbox in textboxNames)
{
  TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
  tbx.Name = "txt_" + counter;
  tbx.AutoSize = true;
  Form1.Controls.Add(tbx);
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any use of `textboxNames` collection. What you need is, group the two `foreach` and create label and textbox together and add them to your Form like below

```
foreach (string label in labelNames)
{
  Label lbl = new Label();
  lbl.Name = "lbl_" + index;
  lbl.Text = label;
  lbl.AutoSize = true;
  Form1.Controls.Add(lbl);


  TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
  tbx.Name = "txt_" + index;
  tbx.AutoSize = true;
  Form1.Controls.Add(tbx);

  index++;
}
```

Comment: Like @Rahul's answer says, your code example doesn't really highlight the need for that second query which you're using to create text boxes. If you stripped out information that you think is irrelevant to your problem and you're committed to keeping that second query then I suppose it comes down to ensuring that your two queries return the same number of records.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than doing them as 2 separate foreach loops you could do it in a single for loop, e.g. (assuming labelNames and textboxNames are `List<string>`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < labelNames.Count; i++)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Name = "lbl_" + labelNames[i];
    lbl.Text = labelNames[i];
    lbl.AutoSize = true;
    Form1.Controls.Add(lbl);

    TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
    tbx.Name = "txt_" + textboxNames[i];
    tbx.AutoSize = true;
    Form1.Controls.Add(tbx);
}
```

Might also be worth checking there are equal numbers of each first as a sanity check:

```
if (labelNames.Count != textboxNames.Count)
{
    //throw exception etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your two foreach loops with a single for loop that iterates through both lists at the same time.:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Math.Min(labelNames.Length, textboxNames.Length); i++)
{
  Label lbl = new Label();
  lbl.Name = "lbl_" + i;
  lbl.Text = textboxNames[i];
  lbl.AutoSize = true;
  Form1.Controls.Add(lbl);

  TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
  tbx.Name = "txt_" + i;
  tbx.AutoSize = true;
  Form1.Controls.Add(tbx);
}
```

The "Math.Min(labelNames.Length, textboxNames.Length)" comparator will make sure the loop stops after whichever list has the fewest entries.  I didn't see either of your labelNames or textboxNames collections defined so I'm not sure whether they're arrays or lists or what, so you may need to change "Length" to "Count".